# Can someone please explain why $A\setminus f^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus F)=f^{-1}(F)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I've been going through the following proof from my Analysis course. I can't understand why the set equation in the (ii) $\Longrightarrow$ (iii) part is true.

It asserts

> $$A\setminus f^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus F)=f^{-1}(F)$$

where $f:A\to\mathbb R$. Can someone explain why this is the case?

[image: Proof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x\in A\setminus f^{-1}[\Bbb R\setminus F]$; then $x\notin f^{-1}[\Bbb R\setminus F]$, so $f(x)\notin\Bbb R\setminus F$. But clearly $f(x)\in\Bbb R$, so this can only mean that $f(x)\in F$ and hence that $x\in f^{-1}[F]$. This shows that

$$A\setminus f^{-1}[\Bbb R\setminus F]\subseteq f^{-1}[F]\;.$$

Now suppose that $x\in f^{-1}[F]$. Then $f(x)\in F$, so $f(x)\notin\Bbb R\setminus F$, and therefore $x\notin f^{-1}[\Bbb R\setminus F]$. But $x\in A$, so $x\in A\setminus f^{-1}[\Bbb R\setminus F]$, and we’ve now shown that

$$f^{-1}[F]\subseteq A\setminus f^{-1}[\Bbb R\setminus F]$$

and hence that

$$A\setminus f^{-1}[\Bbb R\setminus F]=f^{-1}[F]\;.$$

Comment: Ah okay, so it's not obvious; i.e. it requires a proof. I assumed (judging from the way it was written) that it appeared obvious.

Comment: @Luke: What’s obvious depends on the viewer: many *would* consider it obvious, though that is to some extent a matter of experience. However, you should be aware that it’s also true that proofs often leave out steps that the author considers easy enough that the reader should be able to complete them without much difficulty — not necessarily instantaneously, but at least fairly routinely.